# Finding moments of Binomial distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Consider a binomial distribution
$$p(n_1)={}^NC_{n_1} p^{n_1}q^{N-n_1}$$
As per my text the moments can be found as
$$p^{n_1}n_1^{m}=\left( p\frac{\partial }{\partial p}\right)^mp^{n_1}$$
\begin{align*}
\langle  n_1^m\rangle &= \sum_{n_1}{}^NC_{n_1} p^{n_1}q^{N-n_1} n_1^{m} \\
&= \sum_{n_1}{}^NC_{n_1} \left( p\frac{\partial }{\partial p}\right)^mp^{n_1}q^{N-n_1} \\
&= \left( p\frac{\partial }{\partial p}\right)^m\sum_{n_1}{}^NC_{n_1} p^{n_1}q^{N-n_1} \\
&= \left( p\frac{\partial }{\partial p}\right)^m(p+q)^N
\end{align*}

Now what they do, is to act the derivatives one by one and then in the final result use $p+q=1$. In [this stack post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4091059/687460) I have asked given $p+q=1$ How do we find the derivative, Most have suggested putting the value of $p+q=1$in the function but if we do so every moment come out to be zero. So Can any explain this reason for the flaw?

Comment: Write $q = 1- p.$ Done.

Comment: If I do so, it would become zero.